# Modify merge request by rewriting history before accepting in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a merge request in Gitlab that is generally ok, but the author unfortunately checked in a few somewhat large build products. I would like to remove them from the history prior to merging using an interactive rebase. Is this possible somehow without asking the author to do it?

I already know how to locally fetch the MR and to do the rebase. But when I push, Gitlab (obviously) does not recognize the MR as accepted.